# Set div height in % inside a div with height and width 100%

Tags: css

I have the current html structure

```
<release_cover> 
    <overlay_controllers>  Green Div </overlay_controllers>
    <img src="blu.div" />
</release_cover>
```

And I want to achieve[image] this:

The img tag is the blue container.
The magenta is the release_cover tag.

I have problem in setting the overlay_controller tag (the green) at a 20% height, exactly positioned at 80% of the container.

So far i did:

```
release_cover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative; 
} 

release_cover img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

overlay_controllers{
  min-height: 20%;
  margin-top: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately the height of the green div depends on what's inside and not a fixed 20%.

Suggestions?

(example with the suggestions received so far: https://jsfiddle.net/82Lb0nhe/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `absolute` position along with `top`, while also not allowing a `height` greater than `300px` it will compute correctly:

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
overlay_controllers {
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fc0;
}
release_cover {
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
release_cover img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fL98w9of/

Comment: when i add display: block;  to the release_cover img, it does fix the problem as well. Wonder what's the differing between introducing top: 0px and change the display of the picture ?!

Comment: @Snick I'm not sure why, some CSS behavior is just plain weird sometimes. As long as it works one does not really have to know why :D

Answer (score 1):

You could position overlay_controllers using **top** instead of **margin-top** property:

```
release_cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
release_cover img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
overlay_controllers {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work:  https://jsfiddle.net/82Lb0nhe/  if you take a look the main container is set to 300x300, but the inner release_cover get's to a odd 300x304. therefore the top: 80% is calculated on 304 rather than 300px.

Comment: You forgot to set height:100% for release_cover: https://jsfiddle.net/82Lb0nhe/3/